# Django Cannot Import File in Subdirectory

Tags: python, django, python-import

I'm almost certain I'm missing something obvious, but imports have plagued me for a while.

I have the following app structure in a larger Django project:

```
\reporting\
\reporting\__init__.py
\reporting\<all other default django files>
\reporting\utils\__init__.py
\reporting\utils\base_file.py
\reporting\utils\appname_reporting.py
```

I am trying to import `appname_reporting` to my `\reporting\views.py`.

I have tried `import utils.appname_reporting`, `from utils import appname_reporting`, and `from .utils import appname_reporting`. All of them give me an error: `ImportError: No module named 'appname_reporting'`.

There are no other files importing `appname_reporting.py`. And `appname_reporting.py` imports `base_file.py`.

**Update**

I got the `appname_reporting` to import in the `views.py`, but now I have a broken import in `appname_reporting` saying it can't import `base_file`. In there I simply have `import base_file`, and it it fails in my tests. I also tried `import .base_file` and it fails.

Comment: The full traceback is usually very important..

Answer (score 0):

You need to have `/reporting` in your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable. Check that it is included in the output of

```
import sys
for p in sys.path: 
    print p
```

After that you can use relative imports:

```
appname_reporting.py:
from . import base_file

views.py
from .utils import appname_reporting
```

Watch out for circular imports however (e.g. if you're importing something in the `__init__.py` files).

You can run Python with the verbose switch:

```
python -v views.py
```

to see what is being imported, and in which order. It will tell you if you have a circular import.